# Is it possible to modify a lattice before using it as a guide for lattice modifier without it instantly distorting your mesh?

Tags: lattice

I have quite complex snaky shape and I'd want to use lattice modifier to change it. Let's say the object is S-shape in 3 dimensions. So using a big cube lattice doesn't work because the control points are randomly scattered around the snaky shape.

I was hoping I could create something like a long cube lattice object, edit that to match the shape and use that as a starting lattice for the lattice modifier. So that initially it doesn't change anything when you add the modifier and add that lattice as its target. But has already the general shape of the snaky shape to make adjusting the lattice easier. I hope you understand what I mean/want.

I made a blend that shows the issue:

https://uploadfiles.net/50q/latticing.zip

https://ufile.io/a5yq5ofb

I hope those work for you.

Comment: I think I do. Good question I’d say (but just for future, use blend-exchange.com to upload files, or pasteall.org/blend if it’s too big. Use screenshots as demonstration material when possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you can do anything with a *Lattice* as the lattice cage transformation in *Edit* mode, to make it fit to the snake profile, will transform the snake shape as soon as you'll activate the *Lattice* modifier. What you can do is use a *Mesh Deform* modifier as it works differently, you need to select an edge of your snake, extrude, make it a sort of cage:

[image]

Then give your object the *Mesh Deform* modifier, choose the cage as *Object*, click on the *Bind* button, modify the cage shape:

[image]

The other solution would be to have a straight shape for your snake at the beginning, give it a *Lattice* modifier, then a *Curve* modifier, so that you can play with both its thickness and shape, but I guess your question is about a snake that has already a S shape.